# CSS selector to find <select> with specified <option> label

Tags: jquery, html, xpath, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I need a CSS selector that selects a `<select>` element if it contains an `<option>` which contains or equals (both would match my requirements) a specified text. Example HTML:

```
<select name="foo">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

I want the `<select>` if it contains for example an option labeled "Second". Something like this:

```
select[option:contains('Second')]
```

If there is no way to achieve that with CSS selectors, i'd also accept JQuery or XPath selectors.

Comment: What do you want to do with the element? Browsers are very limited when it comes to styling `SELECT` elements.

Comment: I want to combine this approach with Selenium methods to automatically find form elements to interact with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS.

You can either use this jQuery selector ([`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector) and [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) are not part of CSS):

```js
$("select:has(option:contains('Second'))")
```

Or this XPath expression:

```
//select[contains(option, 'Second')]
```

Comment: contains matches a sub-string unfortunately. I need to match the value exactly

Comment: @ladieu: `//select[option='Second']` If you're using jQuery you need to manually write a callback to test the value.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('select[name="foo"] option:contains("Second")').parent().addClass('selected');
```

Maybe this can help

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `contains()` selector on the option

```
$("select option:contains('Second')")
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Tn4Z/

and a version with the value attribute not included : http://jsfiddle.net/8Tn4Z/1/

To get the actual select element itself you can simply use the `parent()`method on the above code so that:

```
var selectElement = $("select option:contains('Second')").parent();
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Tn4Z/2/

Comment: Need to select the *-cough-* `select`.